# ObservableCollection привязана к DataGrid, как реализовать поиск и удаление в коллекции?

Tags: c#, wpf

ObservableCollection<class> привязана к DataGrid, как реализовать поиск, сравнение и удаление в коллекции? Если возможно - без использования Linq;

XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,26,0,11" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="212">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Компьютер"  Width="100" Binding="{Binding DG_ComputerName, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP" Width="100" Binding="{Binding DG_IP, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

C#

```
public class DataGridSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Хандлер
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Имя компьютера
    private string _DG_ComputerName;
    public string DG_ComputerName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._DG_ComputerName;
        }
        set
        {
            this._DG_ComputerName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // IP адрес компьютера
    private string _DG_IP;
    public string DG_IP
    {
        get
        {
            return this._DG_IP;
        }
        set
        {
            this._DG_IP = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow (добавляем данные в DataGrid)

```
  private void CollectionStart()
            {
                // Заносим данные в DataGrid
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                // Заносим данные в DataGrid
                collection.Add(new DataGridSource() 
`              `{ DG_ComputerName = "test" + i.ToString(), DG_IP = "test" });
                }
            }
```

**Update**

Для поиска в коллекции использовал foreach, не знаю насколько это правильно, поправьте если этого делать не стоит.

```
bool sep = false;

    // Проверяем, есть ли значение в коллекции DataGrid
    foreach (var i in collection)
    {
        if (i != null)
        {
            if (i.DG_ComputerName.Contains("serq") != true && i.DG_IP.Contains("127.0.0.1") != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Нет в коллекции");
                sep = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Есть в коллекции");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NULL");
        }
    }

    if (sep)
    {
        // Заносим данные в DataGrid
        collection.Add(new DataGridSource() { DG_ComputerName = "serq", DG_IP = "127.0.0.1" });
    }
```

Comment: А в ваша чём проблема? У вас есть `ObservableCollection`, в ней и ищите, добавляйте и удаляйте. Можно даже обойтись без LINQ (хотя и мазохизм, конечно).

Comment: @z668: 1) Индекс в принципе не обязателен. Например, вы можете удалить [по значению](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), если у вас оно есть. С другой стороны, чтобы знать, что именно удалять, вы ведь как-то получаете элемент от пользователя. Если через поиск, вы можете запомнить и индекс. Если пользователь выделяет элемент в `DataGrid`, вы можете узнать [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Так что с вычислением индекса проблема быть не должно.

Comment: @z668: `INotifyPropertyChanged` выглядит правильно, да. Дополнительный плюс за использование `[CallerMemberName]`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы, очень помогли. Жаль [CallerMemberName] работает только на .NET 4.5

Comment: @z668: правильно, вы же создаёте **новый** элемент в `Remove`! Попробуйте так:

    var item = new DataGridSource() { DG_ComputerName = "123", DG_IP = "123" };
    collection.Add(item);

    if (collection.Remove(item))
        MessageBox.Show("True");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("False");

Comment: В общем все сводится к индексу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Закончилось место для комментариев, поэтому перенесу всё в ответ.

У вас есть `ObservableCollection`, в ней нужно искать, добавлять и удалять. Данные в `DataGrid` автоматически обновятся.

Удаление по индексу в принципе не обязательно. Например, вы можете удалить [по значению](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), если у вас оно есть.

С другой стороны, чтобы знать, что именно удалять, вы ведь как-то получаете элемент от пользователя. Если через поиск, вы можете запомнить и индекс. Если пользователь выделяет элемент в `DataGrid`, вы можете узнать [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Так что с вычислением индекса проблем быть не должно.

(`INotifyPropertyChanged` выглядит правильно. Дополнительный плюс за использование `[CallerMemberName]`.)

---

Смотрите. При удалении `Remove` как вы правильно отметили сравнивает значения, и удаляет первое вхождение (или все вхождения, не помню точно). Проблема лишь в том, что непонятно, как сравнивать экземпляры `DataGridSource`. Согласно [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), для сравнения используется `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. Для `Т == string` всё работает, т. к. система знает, как сравнивать строки. Для вашего случая (`Т == DataGridSource`) вам нужно указать метод сравнения. [Для этого нужно](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) либо чтобы `DataGridSource` имплементировал интерфейс `IEquatable<DataGridSource>`, либо перегрузил `Equals(object)` и `GetHashCode`.

Нужная политика зависит от того, *как именно* вы находите элемент для удаления. Если через выделенный пользователем элемент, вы можете использовать `datagrid.SelectedItem`, он даст вам именно нужный элемент из коллекции, который можно скормить функции `Remove` без имплементации сравнения. Если вы хотите удалить элемент по его значениям полей, придётся-таки обеспечить сравнение.

Comment: Только руки дошли, перегрузил Equals(object)/Equals(тип) и GetHashCode - все отлично, спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @z668: отлично, проблема побеждена!

Пожалуйста.